# Retrieve Context in RxBroadcast.fromBroadcast subscription

Tags: android, rx-android, android-broadcastreceiver

Added dependency to Gradle

```
compile 'com.cantrowitz:rxbroadcast:1.0.0'
```

Using `RxBroadcast` inside Service

```
RxBroadcast.fromBroadcast(this, someFilter)
           .subscribe(new Action1<Intent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Intent intent) {
                           //NOTICE : only intent is received. no Context
                        }
                    });
```

Looked inside source code `BroadcastProvider.createBroadcastReceiver` method

```
@NonNull
private BroadcastReceiver createBroadcastReceiver(
        final Subscriber<? super Intent> subscriber) {
    return new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                //NOTICE : context is discarded here.
                subscriber.onNext(intent);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

How can i retrieve `Context` inside `fromBroadcast` subscription ?

Comment: Shortly - you cannot, because only `intent` is being emmited. Of course, unless you change sources and emit a wrapper object with intent and context.

Comment: @azizbekian thanks. I'm trying to call `getSystemService` inside subscription, is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Shortly - you cannot, because only `intent` is being emitted. Of course, unless you change sources and emit a wrapper object with intent and context.

You may get the global application context, and after that you can perform `getSystemService` with that context.

What you have to do is to add your custom `Application` subclass in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:name="com.your.package.MyApplication"
    ...
    >
```

And create MyApplication class itself, that inherits from `android.app.Application`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    static MyApplication application;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        application = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getApplication() {
        return application;
    }
}
```

Now you can call `MyApplication.getApplication().getSystemService()` from within your subscription.

There's only one `Application` instance during the app lifecycle, so no leakage may happen because of keeping static reference.